# Change in vertex factors for inverse process

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, effective-field-theory

Recently I have started learning the "Effective Field Theory". As a part of learning, I was trying to calculate the vertex factor for a process where two unknown neutral spin-1 bosons $Y$ annihilated to Standard Model (SM) gauge bosons $W^{+}$ and $W^{-}$, that is $YY  \rightarrow W^{+} W^{-}$. The interaction vertex is "Fermi" like.

The package [Feynrules](http://feynrules.irmp.ucl.ac.be/) has been employed to compute the vertex and it looks like the following:
\begin{equation}
\left\{(W^{+},1),(W^{-},2)\rightarrow (Y,1),(Y,2)\right\} = -8ia_{1}p_{1}^{\lambda}p_{2}^{\sigma}\eta_{\mu\nu}+3ip_{1}^{\sigma}p_{2}^{\lambda}\eta_{\mu\nu}-8i\eta_{\mu\nu}\eta_{\lambda\sigma}p_{1}.p_{2}+\text{similar ten more terms contaning}~p_{1}^{\mu}p_{2}^{\nu}\eta_{\lambda\sigma}
\end{equation}
Please note that the Wilson coefficients are not written for the sake of brevity and $p_1$, $p_2$ are the momenta for $W^{+}$ and $W^{-}$ respectively.

Here is the problem that I am dealing with: Although my intention is to calculate the vertex factor for  $YY \rightarrow W^{+}W^{-}$ process but Feynrules calculated the factor for the inverse process $  W^{+}W^{-}\rightarrow YY$. In order to get the correct vertex factor for $YY \rightarrow W^{+}W^{-}$ process what change needs to be make? Is it like assigning the momenta $p_{1}$ and $p_{2}$ for Y's instead of $W$'s?
It will be a great help if someone shed some light on this matter.

**Note**: Using standard QFT techniques I tried to do the calculation but it turns out the calculation is long and prone to make errors. I don't know what techniques Feynrules has employed.